# How to delete nomodeset from my grub file in order to boot normally?

Tags: command-line, boot, grub2, nomodeset

How can I delete the option `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub`? Or, more precisely, how can I access a command line in order to delete the option?

I have set it in my grub file trying to debug [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802). Now I can not longer access the Ubuntu recovery mode in order to delete the `nomodeset` from the grub file. I do not know how to get access to a command line without access to the recovery mode.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1 or F7</kbd> does not work. The last messages I get are `starting LightDM display manager` and `stopping save kernel messages` so I think the system does start fine.

Is there a way (keyboard shortcut) to boot into a terminal for instance?

Comment: I do not know what I was thinking this morning. The bounty text should read: "Your answer is well written, it was fast, it saved me the time of figuring this out again. Also I think it is interesting for future reference. Thank you."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If Ubuntu does not work, you can still access your installation via `chroot`.

> Be aware that the live system must have the same architecture (32 or
>   64bit) as your system on the hard disk.

Boot from a Live media of Ubuntu (USB/CD/DVD) and open a terminal (CTR+ALT+T). The general idea here is to mount the (root) partition of Ubuntu and then `chroot` in it.

First give this command to list the partitions

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

here is an example result

```
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    81922047    40857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        81922048   625142447   271610200    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        81924096   140517375    29296640   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       140519424   433487871   146484224   83  Linux
```

If this does not work, you can also use `gparted` (open the dash and type `gparted`) to find what your root partition is.

I know that my Ubuntu (root) partition is /dev/sda5 (because I have a separate /home in /dev/sda6).

Now I will mount the /dev/sda5 in /mnt

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

Now I will connect to /mmt and mount some other folders that might be needed.

```
cd /mnt 
sudo mount -t proc proc proc/
sudo mount -t sysfs sys sys/
sudo mount -o bind /dev dev/
sudo mount -t devpts pts dev/pts/
```

Now I will chroot to my Ubuntu installation

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Edit the file you want.

```
nano etc/default/grub
```

Be careful the forward-slash here. `etc` not need forward-slash in the beginning because you will edit the wrong file then.

Now remove the entry `nomodeset` (or anything else)

save the file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> , then <kbd>Y(es)</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER.</kbd>

now update grub

```
update-grub
```

Exit the chroot enviroment and unmount the folders - partitions

```
exit 
sudo umount {proc/,sys/,dev/pts,dev/}
cd .. ; sudo umount /mnt
```

The changes have been applied.. reboot your system.

[source 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot)

[source 2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root)