# "General error mounting filesystems" after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, 13.04

I just tried updating to 13.04 from 12.10. When I restarted, it went to Grub even though there's no other OS on the computer. I clicked on Ubuntu to finish booting and I got a terminal with the error message:

```
General error mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system.
root@mycomputer:~#
```

Reboot brings me back to the exact same place.

The only other options on Grub are Advanced options for Ubuntu and a couple of memory test options. I ran one of them and it came out fine.

I have no idea what to do next. Please advise.

EDIT:

Per request, here is the contents of /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices 
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>   <type>   <options>        <dump>   <pass>
# /was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5b22f712-cd92-446e-8984-0c31ca17c02c /                ext4     errors=remount
-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=86ea10b7-9309-4860-8ade-059f9d9fa328 none             swap     sw
  0       0
```

Comment: Did you create your /home directory on a separate partition. Probably your system couldn't mount the /home directory. So you're unable to log in with the user you created.

Comment: Please share the contents of /etc/fstab

Comment: @Frank It's a standard install using the whole disc. No separate partitions.

Comment: @thefourtheye How do I access the contents of /etc/fstab when I can't boot the computer?

Comment: I see that you have a shell. I think, you can just do `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: @thefourtheye I've edited it into the original question.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in /var/log/syslog

Comment: @thefourtheye Nothing jumps out at me but it's a lot of information and I don't really know what I'm looking at.

Comment: After getting the shell, can you take a copy of that and upload it to a free file hosting service and share the link here?

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm not sure how I'd do that without the GUI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the steps in Sukmono's answer:

1. Boot on LiveUSB
2. `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
3. `sudo chroot /mnt`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

That much got me an error and a suggestion that I run `sudo apt-get install -f`. I did so and that fixed the problem. After shutting down, removing the LiveUSB, and rebooting, Ubuntu 13.04 booted right up.

Comment: When I do "sudo chroot /mnt" I get a message that says "chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory". Yet I can mount /dev/sda1 to /mnt

Comment: I know this is about a year late, but if you're still running in to issues doing `sudo chroot /mnt`, then try following this to be able to do `sudo chroot /mnt`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270753/how-to-delete-nomodeset-from-my-grub-file-in-order-to-boot-normally/270802#270802

Comment: I had an LVM, which was harder to mount than just `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.linux-sxs.org/storage/fedora2ubuntu.html) and successfully mounted it.

Answer (score 2):

May be the upgrade is'nt complete yet.
I find same problem and trying this:

1. Boot on LiveUSB
2. `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
3. `chroot /mnt`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`