# Filesytem check or mount failed on System Upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade

I tried to do a system upgrade, and everything seemed correctly, but after restart the system didn't boot and receive this error

```
Filesystem check or mount failed
```

There's several answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/362265/324599) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/362265/324599) which recommend to do:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg --configure -a
mount -o remount,ro /
sync
reboot
```

but after first and third command I got:

```
EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

What else should I try?

**EDIT**
Although the message seems to be normal, still the system can't boot. Any Ideas?

Comment: I think this is normal.See this link http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ext4-re-mounting-root-partition-is-this-normal-841085/

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/292119/324599) where is suggested to mount the root partition and do a

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

which reinstalled some missing files and finally the system booted right.