# grub is not showing ubuntu after installing redhat 6.0

Tags: boot, grub2

I had installed Redhat 6.0 over Ubuntu 13.04 and now Ubuntu is not showing in grub list.

I have tried following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x50465045

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   163846934    81923436    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       163846996   625141759   230647382    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       393224192   625141759   115958784   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       163850240   393222143   114685952   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 4233 MB, 4233101312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 514 cylinders, total 8267776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe04d8de0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63     8267775     4133856+   b  W95 FAT32
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@ubuntu:/# cd /boot/grub/
root@ubuntu:/boot/grub# ls
fonts  gfxblacklist.txt  grub.cfg  grubenv  i386-pc  locale
root@ubuntu:/boot/grub# sudo update-grub
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows NT/2000/XP on /dev/sda1
Found Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago) on /dev/sda6
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install another Linux distribution, this distribution (most of them) intends to install its own bootloader in the HDD's MBR. I assume that you have Red Hat's grub installed in you HDD right now.

I will advice you to install Ubuntu grub. You can use a live Ubuntu media and use the [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) program in order to correct the grub installation.

Alternatively you can try to [Chroot](https://askubuntu.com/a/270802/95393) and install Ubuntu grub in /dev/sda

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

No sudo needed, you are already root in chroot.

After that, you can boot into Ubuntu and update-grub . If you have a detection of Red Had's OS problem, you can first mount the partition with Red Hat and then update grub again.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt 
sudo update-grub
```